# Setting the selectedFile to a directory on a FileChooser in Java

Tags: java, jfilechooser

Long time developer, Java newbie.

I'm using a JFileChooser object with a SelectionMode for DIRECTORIES_ONLY.  It is launched from a Browse JButton next to a JTextField where I am storing the directory after a selection has been made.

My question is this:  When I try to select a directory by clicking on my Browse button a second time how can I get it to open with the previously selected directory selected in the File Chooser?  Allow me to expand, I have no problem setting the current directory to the parent of the value in my JTextfield or setting the selected file to the value in my JTextfield, but in either case the actual final branch of the directory I have chosen previously is not selected.

If I do a similar exercise with a file chooser with a SelectionMode of FILES_ONLY; when I set the selected file to the previously selected file it opens to the parent directory and the file is highlighted in the file chooser and it's full path appears in the text field at the bottom of the file chooser.

Here is a stripped down version of my code that should demonstrate what I'm talking about.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;

public class myFrame extends JFrame {
public myFrame() {

JLabel lblProjDir = new JLabel("Project Directory:");
JTextField txtProjDir = new JTextField(System.getProperty("user.home"));
JButton btnBrowse= new JButton("...");
JButton btnOK = new JButton("OK");

add(lblProjDir);
add(txtProjDir);
add(btnBrowse);
add(btnOK);

btnBrowse.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
JFileChooser fileDialog = new JFileChooser();
fileDialog.setSelectedFile( new java.io.File(txtProjDir.getText()));
fileDialog.setDialogTitle("Set Working Project Directory");
fileDialog.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
fileDialog.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

if (fileDialog.showOpenDialog(btnBrowse) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
txtProjDir.setText("" + fileDialog.getSelectedFile());
} } } );

btnOK.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
setVisible(false);
//Do some other actions here with data collected
dispose();
}
} );

setSize(200, 200);
setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,200));
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
new myFrame();
}
} );
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: @mascoj I appreciate you trying to help but I do not think you grasp what I am trying to achieve.  Perhaps I am not explaining it clearly enough. Let me try again.

Comment: If I have a file dialog that has a selectionMode of FILES_ONLY and I set the selected file, it opens a file dialog to the parent directory of the file and puts the file's full path in the File Name field of the dialog. This is the desired behavior for folders.

Comment: If I have a file dialog that has a selectionMode of DIRECTORIES_ONLY I have no way of supplying a value to appear in the Folder Name field of the dialog.  If I use setCurrentDirectory it opens to that location with nothing in the Folder Name field.  If I setSelectedFile to a directory path, it uses the parent directory for the CurrentDirectory when opening the dialog but the Folder Name field again is left blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using setSelectedFile, use [setCurrentDirectory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setCurrentDirectory(java.io.File)) instead.

To access parent directory use the [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) factory to create a Path and retrieve its parent:

```
Paths.get( <directory path> ).getParent();
```

This will return null if no parent exists. You can retrieve the path string with toString().

Comment: Using setCurrentDirectory opens the file chooser to the directory previously selected and basically prompts to select a directory below it.  I want to be able to open the selected directory's parent and have the selected directory appear as selected the same way a file does.  If you change the DIRECTORIES_ONLY to FILES_ONLY in the code above you can get an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.